# Tweepy won't import on Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, tweepy

I am using Anaconda (Windows 64) and a custom environment named 'twitter' with Python 3.6.  I have installed tweepy in the environment and despite appearing in the list of packages, whenever I run a script simply saying `import tweepy` in the command window I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I have uninstalled/installed tweepy several times using both `pip install` and `conda install` as a few resources suggest and it has not made a difference.  How can I use tweepy successfully?

Full result:

```
(twitter) C:\Users\Michael\Documents\import_t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Documents\import_t.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

Comment: Try Conda install

Comment: try to do pip freeze and check if tweepy is available in the current environment

Comment: I did, and it says ‘tweepy==3.5.0’

Comment: Open a command prompt with Admin rights. Uninstall tweepy. Now install again, but carefully review for any error messages.